How do Facebook post embeds appear in dark mode on iOS?
I am trying to embed facebook post in my app in iOS.
Using the embed generator provided by Facebook, I can get the code. It all works fine in light mode but when I switch to dark mode, the background does change to black but the text color doesn't change.
It remains black, thus it looks like a black text on black background, thus it blends and nothing is visible.
Here is my code,
<div class="embed-facebook-post">
   <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/babalilachocolate/posts/pfbid033rJeUdXXam2jJZNCA12QUyeZZivmQq7MTtDGiuiXVu6St3WEMpwecNu4iC2yqJ9Wl" data-width="500" data-show-text="true">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/babalilachocolate/posts/536751285131885" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<p>✨At the heart of Baba Lila is The Twelve Truffles✨
It all began with them. Tash has been making these 12 flavours since...</p>
Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/babalilachocolate">Baba Lila</a> 
on&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/babalilachocolate/posts/536751285131885">Thursday, November 24, 2022</a></blockquote>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- This is part of my css --!>
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  div.embed-facebook-post {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

So far I found this similar issue asked here.
https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/extension/mediaembed/support/topic/177161
How to change the text color of the fb post to white so that it is visible in dark mode?

What do you see when you use your browser devtools inspect facility - exactly from where is the color being set?

The plugin loads as an external iframe, so you can not modify anything inside of it from the outside.

@CBroe I wonder how it works in Android then? In Android, it shows me black background with white text color fb post in dark mode.

That'll be the plugin itself detecting darkmode then, not the effect of your CSS.
